# 400 error when downloading file with "Authorization" header

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, urlrequest

The server returning a json file that is:

```
{"ctrl":{"code":400,"text":"Not valid Access token","ts":"2020-03-05T11:54:01.547Z"}}
```

Code:

```
public func startDownload(url: URL, pathURL: URL) {
        let accessToken: String! = "Bearer \(Constants.access_token)"
        self.dirURL = pathURL
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        guard let token = accessToken else { return }
        request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: request)
        downloadTask.resume()
}
```

FYI: access token is valid, it is working with Postman.

Comment: can you share the debug request, please

Comment: check the value of `token` put a breakpoint or try printing it.

Comment: @KeshuR. `token` is not nil and it is valid

Comment: backend log shows that access token is empty, but actually it is not empty

Comment: Are you sure your sever expects authorization header in exactly that format?

Comment: @mag_zbc yes, I'm sure, it is working also on android client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have a problem because, unfortunatelly, there's no good solution to this issue. `Authorization` is one of the [Reserved HTTP Headers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest#1776617) and setting it either in `URLRequest` header, or in `URLSessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders` may simply not work:

> If you set a value for one of these reserved headers, the system may ignore the value you set, or overwrite it with its own value, or simply not send it.

One might expect you could provide this token in `URLSessionTaskDelegate` method `urlSession(_:task:didReceive:completionHandler:)` which handles authentication challenges, but in there you need to provide a `URLCredential` object, and sadly it doesn't have a constructor that takes a `Bearer` token, so that's a no-go.

So basically, short of writing your own `URLProtocol` implementation, your best bet would be to send the token in some additional, custom, header field and have the server grab it from there (if you have control over server code). [Source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/89811)

Comment: It works, I have changed "Authorization" to "X-Authorization". Thanks.